# SFMC SQL query most recent record MAX()

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, activities

Hi everybody iam facing some issues.
 I want to create a sql activity which gives me the most recent record based on my date field called ***(created date)*** from DE: **integration 2play** and saves those records (green) only to new DE.

***  Due to comments i changed code accordingly but still getting error:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.***

Any suggestions?

Please find my code below.

Hope any body can help me out.

[image]

```
 SELECT ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number], [last login], MAX[created date] as [created date], [email address]    
    FROM [integration 2play]           
    GROUP BY ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number], [last login], [email address]
```

Comment: What issues are you seeing with the code you have? Is it erroring, returning incorrect answers or null? etc...

Comment: Hi @Gortonington sorry i got the error: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

From Data Extension is called "integration 2 play"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like just some syntax errors.  As @Data_Kid pointed out there were issues with extra commas and you needed to bracket or double quote the DE name.

He was missing one item though, `Max[Created Date]`  needed parenthesis around it to utilize the Max function.

Example:

```
SELECT ID1
, ID2
, Name
, [Phone number]
, [last login]
, MAX([created date]) as [created date]
, [email address]    
    FROM [integration 2play]           
    GROUP BY ID1
    , ID2
    , Name
    , [Phone number]
    , [last login]
    , [email address]
```

Comment: Snap!!+1 was stumped

Comment: of course both of you :) @Data_Kid  & Gortonington

Comment: I have one more question. If iwould have a second "Date" field and i have to compare both and capture only the most recent date out of these two its ONLY archievalble by using CASE statement and when NULL value using COALESCE?  Am i right on that?

Comment: Like: SELECT ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number], MAX[last login] as [last login], MAX[created date] as [created date], [email address] FROM [integration 2play] GROUP BY ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number],  WILL NOT WORK as 2 MAX statements are used? @Data_Kid :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the DE name in brackets `[integration 2play]` and take out the `,`' from after `[email address]`

```
 SELECT ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number], [last login], MAX[created date] as [created date], [email address]    
    FROM [integration 2play]
    WHERE [created date] >= DATEADD(dd,-1,getdate())

    GROUP BY ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number], [last login], [email address]
```

Also you dont need the `WHERE [created date] >= DATEADD(dd,-1,getdate())` since you are using the MAX(created date], it becomes redundant.

```
SELECT ID1
, ID2
, Name
, [Phone number]
, [last login]
, MAX[created date] as [created date]
, [email address]    
FROM [integration 2play]
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, Name, [Phone number], [last login], [email address]
```

Comment: thank you i changed it i now receive:
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: also take out the `,' after the `[email address]`

Comment: thank you for the hints but sadly it still says: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.